# Generate thumbnail from the center of existing bigger image

Tags: php, thumbnails

I've read some time ago about the idea of generating a thumbnail image from a bigger image not starting from the top left corner but from the center of the bigger image.

Can anybody tell how to do that with php?

Comment: accept some of your 4 questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For resizing of any kind, you usually use one of the [`imagecopy`](http://php.net/imagecopy) methods:

```
imagecopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y ,
            int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

The `src_` parameters specify what part of the source image to copy. Just make that anything other than 0, 0.

Comment: For better results use `imagecopyresampled()`.

Comment: True, depending on what exactly you want to copy where. Added small note.